# Issues in import sql in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql

While importing the sql data, it shows syntax error:

Here is my code:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tblproduct` (
  `id` int(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `code` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `image` text NOT NULL,
  `price` double(10,2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `product_code` (`code`)
)

INSERT INTO `tblproduct` (`id`, `name`, `code`, `image`, `price`) VALUES
(1, '3D Camera', '3DcAM01', 'product-images/camera.jpg', 1500.00),
(2, 'External Hard Drive', 'USB02', 'product-images/external-hard-drive.jpg', 800.00),
(3, 'Wrist Watch', 'wristWear03', 'product-images/watch.jpg', 300.00);
```

I just confused with this, what is the exact error.

Can anyone help me to fix this? thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there any specific error you are getting?

Comment: add a ';' after your `CREATE TABLE` statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it's whole generated so there should be no errors. Try to add semicolon after create table syntax so each query is separated. Like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tblproduct` (
  `id` int(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `code` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `image` text NOT NULL,
  `price` double(10,2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `product_code` (`code`)
);

INSERT INTO `tblproduct` (`id`, `name`, `code`, `image`, `price`) VALUES
(1, '3D Camera', '3DcAM01', 'product-images/camera.jpg', 1500.00),
(2, 'External Hard Drive', 'USB02', 'product-images/external-hard-drive.jpg', 800.00),
(3, 'Wrist Watch', 'wristWear03', 'product-images/watch.jpg', 300.00);
```